# Make a link to pdf document in leaflet popup for markers

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have markers on a map that has more info in a pdf document that I want to ad as a link in the popup for the marker. I have all pdf documents in "doc" folder and the pdf has the same name as the ID of the marker, to be able to have the correct pdf file open for the specific marker. Marker with "ID 1099" has a pdf with the name "1099.pdf" as an example. The problem is that when using this below sample code it opens a new window with what seems to be the correct address but no pdf file is shown, it looks like it tries to open a large file but they are only a few hundreds of Kb and should be open in a sec. The website freeze at this moment and I am not able to do anything without restarting the browser.

Is there a better way to do this? What is wrong with this code?

```
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  var popupText = "Project: " +'<b>' + feature.properties.Project_name + '</b> ' +
      "<br>Organisation: " + '<b>' + feature.properties.Organisation + '</b>' + 
      "<br>Address: " + '<b>' + feature.properties.Address + '</b>' +
      "<br>Zipcode City: " + '<b>' + feature.properties.zipcode + ',  ' + feature.properties.city + '</b>' +
      "<br>Latest update: " + '<i><b>' + feature.properties.date + '</i></b>' +
      "<br>" + '<a href="/html/data/doc/' + feature.properties.id + '.pdf"' + 'target="_blank"' + '>More info</a>'
      ;

  layer.bindPopup(popupText, {
    closeButton: true,
    offset: L.point(0, -20)
  });
  layer.on('click', function() {
    layer.openPopup();
  });
},
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your javascript code but with your pdf files. Try if you can open a pdf file directly in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, yes I should have tested that more properly, the error was "html" in the link, when removed everything worked as it should. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I used /html/ in the link, by removing html to instead `/data/doc/` the link worked